# Rails 4.2.3 Devise setup with Controller-specific Assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, asset-pipeline

I am using the [Controller-specific Assets configuration](http://theflyingdeveloper.com/controller-specific-assets-with-rails-4/), it woks perfectly except with the newly installed [Rails-Devise] authentication bundle (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).

For instance on **registration page** (controller devise/registrations), The assets on `/stylesheets/devise/registrations.css` and `/javascripts/devise/registrations.js`are not loaded (404).

Devise works fine when I reactivate both the

**application.js**

`//= require_tree .`

and

**application.css**

`*= require_tree .`

but :
Is it possible to add devise gem's assets in a way that allows to keep the controller specific assets ?

Thanks,

Comment: What is the name of the controller (namespace included)? Are you sure `/stylesheets/devise/registrations.css` is the URL that is trying to load? and returns a 404)

Comment: Yes @Marc-AlexandreBérubé, this is what the console displays, quite unusual path. I think it is a side effet to the removal of automatic assets load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Devise doesn't have any stylesheet or javascript assets](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/master/app).

--

You'll be best using some conditional logic in your layout, to determine whether you're using a `devise_controller` or not:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
stylesheet_link_tag :application, (controller_name unless devise_controller?)
```

This uses the [`devise_controller?` helper](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-custom-layouts)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rich this fixed my issue